# Installing GNU Assembler in OSX

Tags: macos, assembly, gnu-assembler

No matter how hard I google, I can't seem to find a (relatively) easy-to-follow instruction on how to install the GNU Assembler on a mac.

I know I can use `gcc -c` (Apple Clang on a Mac) to assemble `.s` / `.S` files, but I want to use actual GNU Binutils `as`.

Comment: Which assembler?  XCode already comes with assemblers for Intel and ARM (if you have the iPhone SDK).

Comment: I am looking to install 'gas' : I'm just starting out so please excuse me if I am not answering your question correctly.

Comment: Do you have the developer tools installed?  A quick check on my system shows assemblers for arm, i386, ppc, ppc64, and x86_64.  Do you need a special assembler?  What are you trying to do?

Comment: Yes, I do. 
I understand that Xcode uses assemblers and therefore comes with one for Intel. Now I need to find a way to actually build my code using Xcode.

Comment: I am taking a class on Computer Organization. We are learning IA-32 assembly.

Comment: In XCode all you have to do is add an assembly file to your project.  The right things will happen.  The other option is to run the assembler from the command line:

`as myfile.s` should do it for you.  So should `gcc myFile.s`.

Comment: Wouldn't this belong on Superuser or something?

Comment: Got it. Thanks. I was kinda lost.

Comment: @CarlNorum Isnt it obvious that the GNU assembler uses AT&T syntax, and that is (i hope) what he wants?

Answer (score 4):

[`yasm`](https://yasm.tortall.net) works on Mac OSX (I got it from Homebrew), and it has a GNU `as` syntax parser which can be enabled with `-p gas` (it may be necessary to also add `-r gas`). It is not 100% complete, but it covers mostly everything. It can output to a variety of object formats (if cross-compiling is necessary), and in my opinion it's pretty cool. You can also use NASM syntax (which is completely supported) using `-p nasm` (again, `-r nasm` may be necessary).

Sorry about necroposting, but this is a still-relevant question and I believe that it needs an acceptable answer.

Comment: I think I read some mention of a macports build of `gobjdump`.  Is there a similar build of `gas`?  I don't have a Mac so I can test it.  (But yes +1 for YASM, good idea.  Unfortunately it's not been kept up to date; it doesn't support AVX512 instructions.  But if you don't need that it's good, and has better long-NOP support than NASM)

Comment: I cannot find a `gas` build from MacPorts, unfortunately. I don't have AVX-512 on my Macbook, and so I didn't realize that YASM was incomplete in this regard. What assembler do you use, @PeterCordes? NASM doesn't have as much documentation or directive support as I'd like, and YASM doesn't look updated at all (see their GitHub https://github.com/yasm/yasm). I've heard about FASM, MASM, TASM, etc. but I haven't tried them out.

Comment: I don't have a Mac.  I usually use YASM or NASM for hand-written asm experiments. (On GNU/Linux.)  I use GAS / AT&T syntax for inline asm sometimes, but almost always I just read asm when doing actual programming, and tweak my C source to get efficient asm.  If I was on a Mac, I'd probably just use GAS, probably with Intel-syntax mode, because NASM has had bugs with relocations for rip-relative and absolute addressing modes in its MachO64 output format support.  But with a working version of NASM, sure I'd probably use that.

Comment: I think the OP is looking for a way to specifically get GNU as on their osx machine.  That's what I was looking to do when I stumbled onto this post as well.

Comment: does yasm work on M1 machines like newer MacBooks? I seem to just get segmentation faults. There's very little authoritative documentation on assmblers for newer Macs.

Answer (score 3):

The GNU assembler cannot (yet) be used to create native object files (of Mach-O format). But you can of course use it to cross-assemble for some non-native object format, if that is what you want.

Comment: I found this post [Can't seem to get gcc or binutils to build a new linker or assembler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9574023/cant-seem-to-get-gcc-or-binutils-to-build-a-new-linker-or-assembler) where a responder mentions no support for as and ld on os x.

Answer (score 0):

The gnu assembler is already installed on your mac (assuming that you installed the dev tools package).  If you want to avoid XCode, you can invoke it from the command line with `as`, or with the preprocessor by using `gcc yourfile.s $(OPTIONS)`.

---

Edit: `as` now points to the clang assembler; at the time this answer was written it pointed to (Apple's build of) the GNU assembler.

Comment: That is true. Except that the included one is not the GNU assembler.

Comment: That gcc is an alias for clang. gcc --version gives

Configured with: --prefix=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr --with-gxx-include-dir=/usr/include/c++/4.2.1
Apple LLVM version 8.1.0 (clang-802.0.38)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin16.5.0
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin

Comment: @Olsonist It was the gnu assembler *at the time this answer was written*.

Comment: gcc normally only runs asm through the C preprocessor for `.S` filenames, not `.s`.  IDK about Apple clang (which is what `gcc` on MacOS runs these days!).

Answer (score -2):

**Maybe `as` instead of `gas` ?** If you want to have gas as command invoke this: `echo "alias gas=as" >> $HOME/.profile`

It was installed on my Mac Lion when i opened the terminal and typed it. It might have been because of [MacPorts](http://www.macports.org/) and/or XCode as mentioned in the comments of a previous answer.

Comment: as is the llvm assembler as --version gives Apple LLVM version 8.1.0 (clang-802.0.38)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin16.5.0
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin